# Spider won't run after updating Scrapy

Tags: python-2.7, scrapy

As seems to frequently happen here, I am quite new to Python 2.7 and Scrapy. Our project has us scraping website date, following some links and more scraping, and so on. This was all working fine. Then I updated Scrapy.

Now when I launch my spider, I get the following message:
[image]

This wasn't coming up anywhere previously (none of my prior error messages looked anything like this). I am now running scrapy 1.1.0 on Python 2.7. And none of the spiders that had previously worked on this project are working.

I can provide some example code if need be, but my (admittedly limited) knowledge of Python suggests to me that its not even getting to my script before bombing out.

**EDIT:**
OK, so this code is supposed to start at the first authors page for Deakin University academics on The Conversation, and go through and scrape how many articles they have written and comments they have made.

```
import scrapy
from ltuconver.items import ConversationItem
from ltuconver.items import WebsitesItem
from ltuconver.items import PersonItem
from scrapy import Spider
from scrapy.selector import Selector
from scrapy.http import Request
import bs4

class ConversationSpider(scrapy.Spider):
name = "urls"
allowed_domains = ["theconversation.com"]
start_urls = [
    'http://theconversation.com/institutions/deakin-university/authors']


#URL grabber
def parse(self, response):
    requests = []
    people = Selector(response).xpath('///*[@id="experts"]/ul[*]/li[*]')
    for person in people:
        item = WebsitesItem()
        item['url'] = 'http://theconversation.com/'+str(person.xpath('a/@href').extract())[4:-2]
        self.logger.info('parseURL = %s',item['url'])
        requests.append(Request(url=item['url'], callback=self.parseMainPage))

    soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(response.body, 'html.parser')
    try:          
        nexturl = 'https://theconversation.com'+soup.find('span',class_='next').find('a')['href']
        requests.append(Request(url=nexturl))
    except:
        pass
    return requests

#go to URLs are grab the info
def parseMainPage(self, response):
    person = Selector(response)
    item = PersonItem()
    item['name'] = str(person.xpath('//*[@id="outer"]/header/div/div[2]/h1/text()').extract())[3:-2]
    item['occupation'] = str(person.xpath('//*[@id="outer"]/div/div[1]/div[1]/text()').extract())[11:-15]
    item['art_count'] = int(str(person.xpath('//*[@id="outer"]/header/div/div[3]/a[1]/h2/text()').extract())[3:-3])
    item['com_count'] = int(str(person.xpath('//*[@id="outer"]/header/div/div[3]/a[2]/h2/text()').extract())[3:-3])
```

And in my Settings, I have:

```
BOT_NAME = 'ltuconver'
SPIDER_MODULES = ['ltuconver.spiders']
NEWSPIDER_MODULE = 'ltuconver.spiders'

DEPTH_LIMIT=1
```

Comment: Show your files. This is typo error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently my six.py file was corrupt (or something like that). After swapping it out with the same file from a colleague, it started working again 8-\